# Crypted_password is null when using Authlogic to save a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, authlogic

i'm getting a strange error on my production install when i try and
create a new user using AL:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Column
'crypted_password' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `users`

especially strange b/c it works as expected on my local box.

RUnning Rails 2.3.2 and ruby 1.8.7 on both boxes.

```
user.rb:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_create :set_username
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.require_password_confirmation = false
    c.login_field = "email"
    c.validates_length_of_password_field_options = {:minimum => 4}  
    c.validate_login_field = false  #don't validate email field with additional validations 
  end
end
```

Here's output from my production console:

```
>> u = User.new
=> #<User id: nil, username: nil, email: nil, crypted_password: nil,
    password_salt: nil, persistence_token: nil, single_access_token: nil,
    perishable_token: nil, login_count: 0, failed_login_count: 0,
    last_request_at: nil, current_login_at: nil, last_login_at: nil,
    current_login_ip: nil, last_login_ip: nil, created_at: nil,
    updated_at: nil, is_admin: 0, first_name: nil, last_name: nil>

>> u.full_name = 'john smith'
=> "john smith"
>> u.password = 'test'
=> "test"
>> u.email = 't...@example.com'

=> "t...@example.com"
>> u.valid?
=> true
>> u.save

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Column
'crypted_password' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `users`
(`single_access_token`, `last_request_at`, `created_at`,
`crypted_password`, `perishable_token`, `updated_at`, `username`,
`failed_login_count`, `current_login_ip`, `password_salt`,
`current_login_at`, `is_admin`, `persistence_token`, `login_count`,
`last_name`, `last_login_ip`, `last_login_at`, `email`, `first_name`)
VALUES('B-XSXwhO7hkbtISIOyEq', NULL, '2009-07-31 01:10:44', NULL,
'FK3mYS2Tp5Tzeq5IXE1z', '2009-07-31 01:10:44', 'john', 0, NULL, NULL,
NULL, 0,
'2c76b645f761eb3509353290e93874cecdb68a63caa165812ab1b126d63660757090ecf69995caef9e78f93d070b524e2542b3fec4ee050726088c2a9fdb0c9f',
0, 'smith', NULL, NULL, 't...@example.com', 'john')
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:212:in `log'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:320:in `execute'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:
259:in `insert_sql'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:330:in `insert_sql'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:
44:in `insert_without_query_dirty'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:18:in
`insert'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/base.rb:2902:in `create_without_timestamps'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/timestamp.rb:29:in `create_without_callbacks'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/callbacks.rb:266:in `create'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/base.rb:2868:in `create_or_update_without_callbacks'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/callbacks.rb:250:in `create_or_update'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/base.rb:2539:in `save_without_validation'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/validations.rb:1009:in `save_without_dirty'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/dirty.rb:79:in `save_without_transactions'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `send'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/transactions.rb:229:in
`with_transaction_returning_status'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:
136:in `transaction'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/transactions.rb:228:in
`with_transaction_returning_status'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/
active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save'
```

No idea why this is happening, and especially why this saves a new user on dev but not on production.  Any help is *much* appreciated, thanks!

edit: using Apache & Passenger 2.2.4

Answer (score 8):

acts_as_authentic mixes in password and password= methods. The password= method takes your plain text password, salts it and encrypts it.

Maybe you have redefined the password= method in your user model, like with attr_accessor :password?

Comment: Excellent. I ran into exactly this problem when switching from an older authentication system to authlogic. There was an attr_accessor :password hiding in my user model.

Answer (score 4):

Authlogic fills crypted_password and password_salt with null when you'll overwrite accessors like this

attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

Those params should be in attr_accessible only

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed the same gem versions of authlogic installed in your production/development system?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same error on my copy of a project however another developer has no problems.

Trying this:

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=7414

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your classmapping

ClassMappings.register(

```
  :methods => ["password"]

  )
```